# CakePHP 3 - check variable from controller in model

Tags: php, cakephp, activerecord

I'm newbie in CakePHP, and I need help with this now.

In app I have this variable which is accessiable from controllers.

```
$this->Auth->user('is_admin')
```

I need apply filter for all Finds in Model. So in ContactsTable.php I have this

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options) {  
  $alias = $event->subject()->alias();
  $query->where([$alias.'.deleted is null']);
  return $query;
}
```

Now, I need aplly this "where" only for no admins users. So my question is how I can read `$this->Auth->user('is_admin')` in this model?

Thank you

Comment: As the docs say, [Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html) are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.
Have you tried passing the auth state with the options of `find($type = null, array $options = [])` in your Controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can pass the auth cariable as param to finder:

```
//controller 
$result = $this
    ->Users
    ->find('myCustomFinder' , [
        'is_admin' => $this->Auth->user('is_admin')
    ]);
```

2) Or You can access session variables directly in model, but this not a good practice and this is a little bit harder to test.

```
// model
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options) 
{  
    $is_admin = \Cake\Routing\Router::getRequest()
        ->session()
        ->read('Auth.User.is_admin');

    // edit: 
    if($is_admin) {
       return $query->withAdminStuff();
    }

    return $query->nonAdminStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that I wrote bad explanation for my issue. I don't want set this variable to my sql query as condition, but I need evaluate it with if() in beforeFind before query->where(). Edit: I need this for all queries to this models in whole all.

Comment: Then You can use the second option, and just wrote `if($is_admin) {...}`